# a heaping third spoonful of gratitude

Tags: meaning-in-context

Example:

> To my parents, who once purchased a small LEGO set for a long and frightening plane trip, beginning an obsession with creativity and organization that continues to relax and inspire.
>   Finally, a **heaping third spoonful** of gratitude to Jennifer and Hadden, who continue to inspire and encourage me even as I pound out words and code every day.

I specifically don't understand **heaping third**.

Comment: It's a {heaping {third spoonful}}. I suppose he has given each of his parents a spoonful. Now he's got a third spoonful of gratitude, and it is a heaping spoonful.   *The collector has added a shiny fifth car to his collection.*

Comment: 'Heaped' rather than 'heaping' would maybe sound better / be more grammatical.

Comment: @TRomano the ambiguity comes from the fact that third comes second in the phrase. If it came first it would be more clear.

Comment: @peterG Except that "heaping *container*" is a common phrase in (American) English. For example, in recipes you'll sometimes see "1 heaping cup of flour" or "2 heaping teaspoons of cinnamon". "third" is thus just an inserted word in the phrase "heaping spoonful". -- I don't know if "heaped cup" is used in elsewhere, but I don't believe I've ever encountered it in American cookbooks.

Comment: @JAB: if the order of words in the phrase **heaping third** is changed to **third heaping** it has a different meaning. See my answer.

Comment: @R.M. I'm sure you're right. I should have added 'in Br Eng' to my comment.

Comment: Not only is it AmEng, but it might even have a bit of a "Southern/Western" bias (as opposed to Northeast) to it, as evidenced at the close of each episode of The Beverly Hillbillies, viewers were invited "back next week to this locality, to have a **heapin'** helpin' of their hospitality."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's literally the third dedication in this book, and a heaping spoonful is just a really full spoonful, if you heaped it on so there's a pile overlooking the edge of the spoon, about to fall out.

Comment: Worth noting: this use of *heaping* as an adjective is mostly only American English.  In British English, *heaped* is a close equivalent. Comparison at Google NGrams: [British usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heaped+teaspoon%2Cheaping+teaspoon&year_start=1900&year_end=2010&corpus=18&smoothing=3), [American usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heaped+teaspoon%2Cheaping+teaspoon&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 2):

**The collector has added *a sporty fifth car* to his collection.**

The fifth car added is sporty.  (*Maybe* some of the others are limos or trucks or family stationwagons; we don't know; all we know is that the fifth car is sporty).

**The collector has added *a fifth sporty car* to his collection.**

All five cars are sporty.

Comment: Addendum to the "fifth sporty car" - it's possible the collector in this case has more than just five cars, but only five of them are sporty.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably an **inside joke** as happens in acknowledgements when the author will mention something comical which only the participants would know the meaning of.

> a **heaping third** spoonful of gratitude

is cryptic, but the fact that it's **heaping** he is trying to express not only **very much** but **more than that**

The author is thanking the support of two **dear** and **steadfast** friends.
What immediately comes to mind is having **coffee** or **tea** where the standard question is

> **one or two spoons** of sugar
>   one or two lumps

This is implied with **third**.  They might have drunk a lot of coffee together during late night coding or during the completion of the book (assuming this is from a book).

Answer (score 0):

I think its helpful to break the sentence down to its components.
**A Heaping third spoonful of gratitude**. This is two adjectives along with something called a "partitive". The partitive is simple, its just a multi part expression containing a **count noun** and the word **of**. A **piece** **of** pie, a **slice** **of** bread a **stack** **of** bills.So the sentence is:
adj adj partitive.
A **large** **delicious** "*piece* of *pie*"